# Selenium not navigating firefox to mentioned URL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Selenium opens firefox but does't move forward after that. This combination runs fine on all machines expect mine. I have checked the versions and it seems everything is same on all machines.

Firefox version is : 46.0.1
Selenium version is : 2.53.1

I am not sure why it is not working on my machine only. Can you guys suggest about the same?

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium version 2.53.1, you should use MarionetteDriver but not FirefoxDriver.

you can download the gecko driver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Use the following to launch the browser and run:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<path to geckodriver>/geckodriver.exe");
MarionetteDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

Comment: Firefox version is 46.0.1 and not 47. And FYI, same combinations are working on other machines.